# Parse framework keeps unlinking

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, xcode7

Every time I open my XCode project in XCode 7.1.1, I get the error: "No such module Parse" wherever I import Parse.

However, I have the Parse framework correctly added in my Build Phases, and the only way to fix this is by deleting the Parse framework listed in my Build Phases and re-adding it like I did the first time.

I have to do this every time I reopen an XCode project, and it's extremely annoying, but able to be worked around. Does anyone have any permanent fixes for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using CocoaPods to install Parse for Swift using the following `Podfile`:

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
use_frameworks!

pod 'Parse'
```

Parse can then be installed with

```
pod install
```